# Searching partial word in a arraylist on android

Tags: java, android, listview, search, partial

Im having a lot of problems with searching for part of a word, and then making it find the full result afterwards.

Like if im searching "droid", it looks through my list for anything that contains "droid", if you look at my arraylist underneath it should find "Android"

Arraylist code:

```
private List<String> getModel() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Linux");
    list.add("Windows7");
    list.add("Suse");
    list.add("Eclipse");
    list.add("Ubuntu");
    list.add("Solaris");
    list.add("Android");
    list.add("iPhone");
    return list;
}
```

Here's the rest of my code:

```
public class idchart extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.idchart);        

    /*Resources res = getResources();        
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);*/


    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            android.R.id.text1,
            getModel());
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.srcBox);
    filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

 }
```

Comment: A regex based solution will work.

Comment: I'm curious, how would a List Object be searched via a regex? It doesn't have built in functionality that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, using Regex, as far I know you would have to iterate the list and try to match every entry.

If you want to avoid iteration, you can use a inverted index approach for each character (like NGram) of the word. If you want to search text starting with what the user sends, you can do it with Java Map (Commons MultiMap). If you want to search by "droid", so you would have to index the position of each character and retrieve the relative results. I don't recommend doing that without a Library like Lucene.